# SQL + LEFT JOIN + LIKE + COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, count, left-join

i have to make a SQL query with PDO to get count with a left join and a count of total.

here my DB

TABLE CONTENT

```
ID  |   TYPE        | ACTION                            |
1   |   picture     | ['1324234324', '4545647777']      |
1   |   picture     | ['4545647777', '7888945555']      |
1   |   video       | ['1324234324']                    |
```

TABLE PAGE

```
ID  |   PAGEID                                          |
1   |   1324234324                                      |
1   |   4545647777                                      |
1   |   7888945555                                      |
```

And here my question! I want to get COUNT() for each type by pageid

ex: (this is what i need for the result)

- Page 1324234324 have 1 picture and 1 video
- Page 4545647777 have 2 picture and 0 video
- Page 7888945555 have 1 picture and 0 video

Now my query is :

```
SELECT 
    A.page_name AS page_name, 
    IFNULL(B.countId, 0) AS total_picture, 
    IFNULL(C.countId, 0) AS total_video 
FROM page A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT action, COUNT(id) as countId FROM content WHERE type = 'picture') B ON (B.action LIKE CONCAT('%', A.page_id, '%')) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT action, COUNT(id) as countId FROM content WHERE type = 'video') C ON (C.action LIKE CONCAT('%', A.page_id, '%'));
```

But the result are really not what i expect :-/

Can someone help me with this please? Its been 10 hours and i have no clue :-(

Comment: What is the `id` column for? Why are they all 1?

Comment: Also, this whole thing would probably be easier if you normalize the `content` table

Comment: You have `A.page_id` but there's no column of that name, you have `PAGEID` and `A.page_name` shouldn't you be doing `A.page` and `B.countId` as `B.ID`?. *"But the result are really not what i expect"* - What results "are" you getting right now? Are there any errors, or are you not checking for them? Does the query work in your console, just not in PDO, or have you not written any PDO for it yet? Your question's unclear as is your query.

Comment: And all the ids are '1'?

Comment: yeah my bad, loll not all the same id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
page_name
, (select COUNT(*) from content where type = 'picture' and CONTAINS(action, page.page_id)) as total_picture
, (select COUNT(*) from content where type = 'video' and CONTAINS(action, page.page_id)) as total_video 
from page
```

(or use "like" instead of the CONTAINS)

Comment: (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content WHERE type = 'picture' AND action LIKE CONCAT('%', A.pageid, '%')) AS total_picture

Answer (score 1):

Break down what you need into parts. Write a query for that. Join it together.

You need to find each `pageid` from `page` in each row in `content`. You need the count of rows from `content` that contain a individual `pageid`s.

```
SELECT p.pageid, vid.numVideo, pic.numPicture
FROM page p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT p.pageid, COUNT(id) AS numVideo
  FROM page p
  INNER JOIN content c
    ON c.content LIKE CONCAT('%', p.pageid, '%')
  WHERE c.type = 'video'
  GROUP BY p.pageid
) vid ON vid.pageid = p.pageid
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT p.pageid, COUNT(id) AS numPicture
  FROM page p
  INNER JOIN content c
    ON c.content LIKE CONCAT('%', p.pageid, '%')
  WHERE c.type = 'picture'
  GROUP BY p.pageid
) pic ON pic.pageid = p.pageid
```

To improve performance, change how you store the data. Use a 3rd table to store the relation between content and page. This would allow the new query to take advantage of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT p.pageid, type, count(*) cnt FROM `PAGE` p 
 LEFT JOIN `CONTENT` c ON c.action like concat('%', p.pageid, '%')
 Group By PAGEID, `type`
```

**Note**:

1. `PAGEID` is `archer` column, `ACTION` is `archer`.
2. `PAGEID` and `CONTENT.id` are `id` unique numbers not like your all `1`.